# How to alter code with FOR Each Loop to to avoid Error: 1004 No cells found

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro that looks below header names for items if there is an item it will make it a drop down. Headers are in the 7th row so it starts looking from row 8 and on. The code runs perfectly, except if there is no items below the headers.

Sometimes the user does not need any drop downs for the sheet so they will leave all rows below the headers blank. Which is great for what I am doing but will make the macro throw errors as there is no items to be found.

I essentially need to tweak my code so it is able to stop or exit if no cells are found. This is the macro I need to tweak.

```
Sub AddDropDowns()
Dim cell As Range
Dim iDropDown As Long

With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    For Each cell In .Range("B8", .Cells(8, .Columns.Count).End(xlToRight)).SpecialCells(XlCellType.xlCellTypeConstants)
        AddDropDown Worksheets("DropDownsTT"), iDropDown,     cell.Offset(-1).Value, "='" & .Name & "'!" &     cell.Resize(WorksheetFunction.CountA(cell.EntireColumn) - 1).Address
    Next cell
End With
End Sub
```

Not sure if this piece of code is needed but the macro calls the following subroutine:

```
Sub AddDropDown(sht As Worksheet, dropDownCounter As Long, header As String,     validationFormula As String)
With sht.Range("A1").Offset(, dropDownCounter) '<--| reference passed sheet row 1 passed column
    .Cells(1, 1) = header '<--| write header
    With .Cells(2, 1).Validation '<--| reference 'Validation' property of cell 1 row below currently referenced one
        .Delete

        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:=validationFormula
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = ""
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = ""
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With
End With
dropDownCounter = dropDownCounter + 1
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *could* do this:

```
Dim rng As Range

'...
With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    On Error Resume Next
    Set rng = .Range("B8", .Cells(8, .Columns.Count).End( _
               xlToRight)).SpecialCells(XlCellType.xlCellTypeConstants)
    On Error Goto 0
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
    For Each cell In rng
        AddDropDown Worksheets("DropDownsTT"), iDropDown, _
           cell.Offset(-1).Value, "='" & .Name & "'!" & _
           cell.Resize(WorksheetFunction.CountA(cell.EntireColumn) - 1).Address
    Next cell
    End If
End With
```

but that's kind of untidy, so I would probably use something like:

```
With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    For Each cell In .Range("B8", .Cells(8, .Columns.Count).End( xlToRight))
        If Len(cell.Value) > 0 Then
            AddDropDown Worksheets("DropDownsTT"), iDropDown, _
                cell.Offset(-1).Value, "='" & .Name & "'!" & _
                cell.Resize(WorksheetFunction.CountA(cell.EntireColumn) - 1).Address
        End If
    Next cell

End With
```

Comment: That did it! thank you. such a smart and idea, add an if statement.